# Using airport extreme as an AP with true bridge mode (forwarding 802.1x auth)

Tags: ldap, radius, 802.1, fortigate

So here is my setup. I have a Router (Fortigate) 4 airport Extreme, and a radius/ldap server on a distant server.

I want my user to authenticate with the radius or LDAP server, and be able to create specific policy for each person on the fortigate.

I have tried to authenticate the users on the airport through radius (WPA2 Entreprise) But the airport doesnt ask for radius accounting, so I cant determine who is connected on the fortigate level.

I have try to set up 802.1x authentication on the fortigate, with the airport extreme in bridge mode, but as they still ask for an IP address when connected to the fortigate on the wan port, the fortigate cannot authenticate the airports and the connection isnt establish.

So what I want to do is either find a way to put the airports in true bridge mode ( so the airport doesnt need an ip address and therefor doesnt need to authenticate on the fortigate, only the final client needs authentication)

OR find a way for the airport to send accounting request to the radius.

Any idea do to one of these solution? or any other solution to my problem ? Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: I don't have one to hand, but it seems very odd that the Airport Extreme wouldn't do RADIUS accounting. Even my $20 home router does this!

Comment: idk if accounting is very common for Acces point / router ! not all of them can handle radius Authentication, so Accounting... Whats router do you use ?

Comment: OK, well, to be fair I did replace the firmware with OpenWrt. :)